# Wordpress custom post type and Google maps API

Tags: html, wordpress, google-maps

I have programmed custom post type inside Wordpress and I am using it for submission of properties inside system.

I would like to add google maps functionality where based on adress that someone enters, he automatically gets a place on the map, all on google maps.

Is that possible? How to render correct place on google maps based on html form inut? Im just loking for an idea on this, if someone can give me a hint I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

you most likely need to implement a small plugin that defines a google map shortcode, with the field with location as a parameter.

The reason is that you need to include libraries etc that are not needed for all other pages, and the ability to put the map wherever you need it within said post.

Comment: And is there a way when someone enters adress in html field, that it gets automatically rendered on google maps?

Comment: where is that HMTL field? in the post type? a block?

Comment: Its on a submit post page. So I created custom post type for properties, and created a page template where users can submit their property. On that page I have also a field adress, and now Im trying to make it easy for them to select their location on google maps. The most easiest way would be if google map that is on that page, could render location based on adress field.. I dont know if that is possible?

Comment: so what do they enter in the field address? is that validated? you most likely need to implement https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker and bind it to the field, so that you get valid addresses in the first place. then, use your template code to show the field as a map.

Comment: Wel they enter property adress in that field. Hmm, I found this http://tristandunn.com/projects/jquery-auto-geocoder/ 

Seems very simple. Will try to implement it on to page where users submit their properties, and then on the page where the property / post is listed. Hope it will work